# New symbol introduced in Sympy output

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve the following set of non-linear equations using Sympy

```
(a + x + tan(b /2) * r) / (a + m + tan(g /2) * r) = tan(pi - g)
g + b =  3/2* pi
```

When I provide the equations to Sympy, see code below, I do get an answer, though with a new symbol 'I'  introduced. What is this 'I'? There is no matrixsymbol, so it can' t be an identity matrix.

```
from sympy import solve, symbols, pi, tan, Rational

a, x, b, g, r, m = symbols("a x b g r m")
half = Rational(1, 2)
eq1 = (a + x + tan(b * half) * r) / (a + m + tan(g * half) * r) - tan(pi - g)
rational = Rational(3, 2)
eq2 = g + b - rational * pi

solution = solve((eq1, eq2), b, g, dict=True)
print(solution)
```

Output:

```
[{
  b: I*log(-sqrt((-a - I*a - I*m + r + I*r - x)/(a - I*a - I*m - r + I*r + x))) + 3*pi/2, 
  g: -I*log(-sqrt(-(a + I*a + I*m - r - I*r + x)/(a - I*a - I*m - r + I*r + x)))
}, 
{
  b: I*log((-a - I*a - I*m + r + I*r - x)/(a - I*a - I*m - r + I*r + x))/2 + 3*pi/2,
  g: -I*log(-(a + I*a + I*m - r - I*r + x)/(a - I*a - I*m - r + I*r + x))/2
}
]
```

I have tried to express the equations with the Eq operator (`eq1 = Eq((a + x + tan(b * half) * r) / (a + m + tan(g * half) * r), tan(pi - g))`), but that yields the same results.

## EDIT

for x=m=0, I know that g=b=135deg (3/4*pi rad), as these equations are part of a bigger problem related to a triangle. This can be visualized by:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlin.pyplot as plt

beta = np.linspace(0, 270, num=1000)
gamma = 270 - beta

beta_rad = beta * np.pi / 180.0
gamma_rad = gamma * np.pi / 180.0

A = 500 # holds for any A and R! 
m = 0
dx = 0
R = 250

output = (A + dx + np.tan(beta_rad / 2) * R) / (
    A + m + np.tan(gamma_rad / 2) * R) - np.tan(np.pi - gamma_rad)

plt.plot(beta, output)
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

`I` stands for "imaginary" part of a complex number (to be precise `I = sqrt(-1)`). The result you are getting has no real solution (only the two complex ones).

In pure Python it is denoted as `j`, e.g. `1+2j`.

Comment: Makes sense. However, the solution should still have a real part for both b and g, see my edit. The answer provided does not comply with the visually obtained solution. Do you know what I do wrong? I read that Sympy does not handle trigonometry that well, could that be the case?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answer the `I` is `sqrt(-1)`. However it is stated in that answer that there are no real solutions. Actually the solutions can be given as expressions involving `I` even if they are real. For example substituting the values suggested in the edit we get:

```
In [9]: solution[0][b]
Out[9]: 
     ⎛     ______________________________⎞      
     ⎜    ╱ -a - ⅈ⋅a - ⅈ⋅m + r + ⅈ⋅r - x ⎟   3⋅π
ⅈ⋅log⎜-  ╱  ──────────────────────────── ⎟ + ───
     ⎝ ╲╱   a - ⅈ⋅a - ⅈ⋅m - r + ⅈ⋅r + x  ⎠    2 

In [10]: solution[0][b].subs({a:500, m:0, x:0, r:250})
Out[10]: 
     ⎛      ______________________________ ⎞      
     ⎜-√2⋅╲╱ (-250 - 250⋅ⅈ)⋅(250 + 250⋅ⅈ)  ⎟   3⋅π
ⅈ⋅log⎜─────────────────────────────────────⎟ + ───
     ⎝                 500                 ⎠    2 

In [11]: solution[0][b].subs({a:500, m:0, x:0, r:250}).simplify()
Out[11]: 
3⋅π
───
 4
```

An expression can contain `I` but still represent a real number.